# How to round decimal to an int in c#

Tags: c#

I'am producing decimal such as:

1. `0.8235294117647058823529411765`
2. `0.1764705882352941176470588235`

I'd like to multiply them by `10` then round them. If the second number after the dot is less than `5` then make it `0`. Otherwise, make it `1`. For the above examples, that would be:

1. `8`
2. `2`

The result should be put in a `int`.

Comment: So… `Math.Round(n * 10)`. Reference: [Multiplication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/aa691372%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), [rounding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round.aspx).

Comment: It's a good policy that after you ask a question, look at the "related" sidebar ----->

Comment: how about you google first before asking such questions? i couldn't down-vote as i don't have 125 reputation yet but once i do i will down-vote it..Haha!!

Comment: Closed as duplicate sure, but closed as too localized? Are you kidding me? It's a question about rounding a number.

Comment: @DanielImms: Yes. That and multiplying by 10. Insanely basic and unhelpful. The rounding part is obviously a duplicate, and the multiplying part is just general reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Math.Round()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round.aspx) if you want to keep it as a `decimal` or round to a certain precision.

```
decimal dec = 0.8235294117647058823529411765m;

decimal rounded = Math.Round(dec * 10); // 8m

decimal roundedToOne = Math.Round(dec * 10, 1); // 8.2m
```

---

FYI, an [explicit conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zf02hx8s.aspx) is defined for `decimal` to `int` so you can round down by casting to an `int`

```
int a = (int)(dec * 10); // 8
```

This could be combined with a condition to round the number up and down

```
decimal num = dec * 10;
int a = (int)num + (num % 0 < .5m ? 0 : 1); // 8
```

Comment: That will truncate the number, won’t it?

Comment: Ah true, I'll fix it up.

Answer (score 5):

I thought it is simple.

```
Math.Round(10 * your_decimal);
```

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s2d3xkk.aspx